# Error when using sqlcmd.exe v SSMS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlcmd

I have a stored proc that runs quite a few individual procs as a daily batch. I have been getting the operations guys to execute this process and it is done via sqlcmd.exe. This has been running without issue for the last 3 months or more. Today it has failed part way through the process with either the following errors;

Error converting data type varchar to float.

Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

However if I run the same proc in SSMS, it returns without error and the batch is complete.

The sqlcmd is called in the following way;
`sqlcmd.exe -S <server> -d <database>-U <user>-P <pw> -i "sql_file.sql" -o "sql_file.sql.output.txt"`

There is some casting of data to float/dates which if something is incorrectly set up then this type of error can occur with in the code. However I have checked the raw data and it looks good. Nothing in particular has changed from yesterday to today, so I am not sure what this issue could be. Has anyone seen this before? Is there some fundamental difference in the way sqlcmd processes a script to that of SSMS?

Any help would be appreciated as this sort of thing is a massive time-waster.

Some new information. I get this issue either being run from a client front end, from excel or via SSMS. The issue is that when multiple processes are being run simultaneously on the SQL server, we get convert errors - either varchar to datetime or varchar to int. The situation today is that I have been running a process that is back filling historical data (will take a couple of days to complete) and I managed to consistently get the daily batch to fail. Stopped the back fill and the batch runs without fail.

The fail comes when I am using scaler functions to compute some results against a number of rows. The scaler function is doing a number of converts, casts or parse calls. As this is done as set operation, it is not possible to determine the specific line that fails on.

Has anyone seen this at all?

Is it possible that under a work load condition, the SQL server is not able to use implied working defaults and is looking to explicit database settings which might be in conflict?

I should now be able to consistently replicate this bug and as such try to improve the safety of converts. I am thinking about using PARSE instead of CONVERT, and also TRY_CAST. I know there are some performance issues. Are there any other ideas that could assist with the reliability of CAST/CONVERT/PARSE?

Comment: Why are you running this manually and not through SQL Agent or a job scheduler?

Comment: Because some of the data used in the processing comes from a 3rd party via email when they get to it. Also there is a a number of non-sql checks the ops guys do before the job is run. Plan is to move this to an agent, but we need to fix a lot of up stream processes first.

Comment: Without seeing code, only generic suggestions are possible. The errors are constant source of questions on the internet - every day. Searching for the error will find **many** discussions of how to fix them. Your code probably relies on implicit conversion from string to the 2 mentioned datatypes - and it probably relies on an assumption about the format of information in the related columns. Unfortunately, "providers" can be erratic in providing consistent data. You will need to adjust the code, the data, or both.

Comment: And there is no fundamental difference between sqlcmd and ssms in how they execute code. You may find that they execute with different session settings - which can depend on many factors (including the logon used to establish the connection). First thing to check is the default language of the user.

Comment: After monitoring this issue for a while, I get the same issue when running under SSMS although much less frequently. It is starting to look like a network issue. The days when this issue presents itself is when there is network contention. However it is not clear why a stored proc randomly throws casting errors that are not real. Remains a mystery for now.